# If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are subsets of a finite set $S$, how do we show how many elements of $S$ are contained in at least two of the subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Obviously I know that I have to use the inclusion-exclusion principle but I'm not sure how to start the proof. I have been told that the answer I have to get to is
$$|A ∩ B| + |A ∩ C| + |B ∩ C| − 2|A ∩ B ∩ C|$$
Is this correct? or should I be aiming for another answer?

**EDIT **

so far I have that we want to find
$|(A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ C) - (A ∩ B ∩ C)|$
Is this a correct first step to take?

Comment: You shouldn't aim for any answer. Start from what you already know, to get to final answer.

Comment: Hint : How many elements in atleast two sets? How many in all three?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Cosmo5's comment, and against the backdrop of [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the **foundation** of the principle is that when each region is added, subtracted, added, subtracted, ... the **net effect** is that each region is counted **once.**

From the constraints of the problem, you can consider the following 4 **mutually exclusive** regions:

Region 1 : in A, in B, not in C. 
Region 2 : in A, not in B, in C. 
Region 3 : not in A, in B, in C. 
Region 4 : in A, in B, in C.

As stated, your formula mishandles Region 4, because the effect of the first three terms is that Region 4 is **included three times**.

To offset this, the final term must deduct Region 4 **twice** rather than once.